# Cordova Battery Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have the following code in Cordova

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' http://192.168.1.102/app.php data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/index.js"></script>
    <title>ÍNDICE DE API'S</title>
    <script>
        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
        }

        function onBatteryStatus(status) {
            alert("Level: " + status.level + " isPlugged: " + status.isPlugged);
        }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">    


</body>
```

But the battery plugin not works. I've tried several times different ways, but not work...

Anyone can help me?

Notes:

The file is in a subfolder

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

[ROOT FOLDER]
-www
--css
--js
--img
--js
--folder
 -- -battery.html

My config.xml

http://pastebin.com/JmJNHQUV

Comment: How are you testing this

Comment: @Pedro could you post your project structure and config.xml  ??

Comment: Hello

Post edited

Answer (score 0):

you can install cordova battery plugin using command [read more here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status)

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status`

try this code...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            </div>
            <button onClick="ShowBatteryStatus()">Show Battery Status</button>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>
             function ShowBatteryStatus() {
                window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);
            }
            function onBatteryStatus(status) {
                alert("Level: " + status.level + " isPlugged: " + status.isPlugged);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```